# spark-sql case when works in REPL but code doesnt compile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This code works in REPL but doesnt compile. I guess I am missing an implicit. But

```
people.select(when(people("gender") === "male", 0)
    .when(people("gender") === "female", 1)
    .otherwise(2))
```

Comment: What is the compilation error ?

Comment: Please share some more insight and the Error Log and some Code.

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In non-REPL code you should use the following import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was expecting Intellij to help figure that out and suggest to import this